# How to use pretrained BERT word embedding vector to finetune (initialize) other networks?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, conv-neural-network, bert-language-model

When I used to do classification work with textcnn, I had experience finetuning textcnn using pretrained word embedding with like Word2Vec and fasttext. And I use this process:

1. Create an embedding layer in textcnn
2. Load the embedding matrix of the words used this time by Word2Vec or
   fasttext
3. Since the vector value of the embedding layer will change during training, the network is
   being finetuning.

Recently I also want to try BERT to do this. I thought, 'As there should be few differences to use BERT pretrained embedding to initial other networks' embedding layer and finetuning, it should be easy!' But in fact yesterday I tried all day and still cannot do it.
The fact I found is that, as BERT's embedding is a contextual embedding, especially when extracting the word embeddings, the vector of each word from each sentence will vary, so it seems that there is no way to use that embedding to initialize the embedding layer of another network as usual...
Finally, I thought up one method to 'finetuning', as the following steps:

1. First, do not define an embedding layer in textcnn.
2. Instead of using embedding layer, in the network training part, I
   firstly pass sequence tokens to the pretrained BERT model and get
   the word embeddings for each sentence.
3. Put the BERT word embedding from 2. into textcnn and train the
   textcnn network.

By using this method I was finally able to train, but thinking seriously, I don't think I'm doing a finetuning at all...
Because as you can see, every time when I start a new training loop, the word embedding generated from BERT is always the same vector, so just input these unchanged vectors to the textcnn wouldn't let the textcnn be finetuned at all, right?

**UPDATE:**
I thought up a new method to use the BERT embeddings and 'train' BERT and textcnn together.
Some part of my code is:

```py
    BERTmodel = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert- 
                base-uncased',output_hidden_states=True).to(device)
    TextCNNmodel = TextCNN(EMBD_DIM, CLASS_NUM, KERNEL_NUM, 
                   KERNEL_SIZES).to(device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(TextCNNmodel.parameters(), lr=LR)
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

```py
  for epoch in range(EPOCH):
    TextCNNmodel.train()
    BERTmodel.train()
    for step, (token_batch, seg_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        token_batch = token_batch.to(device)
        y_batch = y_batch.to(device)

        BERToutputs = BERTmodel(token_batch)
        # I want to use the second-to-last hidden layer as the embedding, so
        x_batch = BERToutputs[2][-2]

        output = TextCNNmodel(x_batch)
        output = output.squeeze()
        loss = loss_func(output, y_batch)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I think by enable BERTmodel.train() and delete torch.no_grad() when get the embedding, the loss gradient could be backward to BERTmodel, too. The training process of TextCNNmodel also went smoothly. 
To use this model later, I saved the parameters of both TextCNNmodel and BERTmodel.
Then to experiment whether the BERTmodel was really being trained and changed, in another program I load the BERTModel, and input a sentence to test that whether the BERTModel was really being trained. 
However, I found that the output (the embedding) of original 'bert-base-uncased' model and my 'BERTmodel' are the same, which is disappointing...
I really have no idea why the BERTmodel part did not change...

Comment: Can you show some code? My guess is that you only passed the parameters of the downstream model to the optimizer and those of BERT.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! @Jindřich I upload some of my code and thoughts. Please kindly refer to it!

Comment: Oh I seem to have found a flaw in my code... Maybe I did not make an optimizer for BERTmodel, so BERT did not change? Right?..

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to thanks @Jindřich , thank you for giving me the important hint!  
I think I am almost there when using my updated version code, but I forgot to set an optimizer for BERTmodel.
After I set the optimizer and did the training process again, this time when I load my BERTmodel, I found that the output (the embedding) of original 'bert-base-uncased' model and my 'BERTmodel' are finally different, which means this BERTmodel is changed and should be finetuned.
Here is my final codes, hope it could help you, too.

```py
    BERTmodel = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert- 
                base-uncased',output_hidden_states=True).to(device)
    TextCNNmodel = TextCNN(EMBD_DIM, CLASS_NUM, KERNEL_NUM, 
                   KERNEL_SIZES).to(device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(TextCNNmodel.parameters(), lr=LR)
    optimizer_bert = torch.optim.Adamw(BERTmodel.parameters(), lr=2e-5, weight_decay=1e-2)
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

```py
  for epoch in range(EPOCH):
    TextCNNmodel.train()
    BERTmodel.train()
    for step, (token_batch, seg_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        token_batch = token_batch.to(device)
        y_batch = y_batch.to(device)

        BERToutputs = BERTmodel(token_batch)
        # I want to use the second-to-last hidden layer as the embedding, so
        x_batch = BERToutputs[2][-2]

        output = TextCNNmodel(x_batch)
        output = output.squeeze()
        loss = loss_func(output, y_batch)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        optimizer_bert.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer_bert.step()
```

I will continue my experiments to see if my BERTmodel is really being finetuned.